How does 発せられた differe from 発される?
彼は手すりに近づくと、侮蔑した目で伊織を見下ろした.
"臆病者"
短くも、重たく。冷淡に発せられた不名誉の言葉。
I don't quite understand what 発せられた is. Is it different from the passive?

This question is similar to: Causative-Passive Verbs: Vせられる and Vされる. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Sorry but how? The short causative form of 発せられた shouldn't be  発すせられた?

発 is a suru-verb. Thus plain form する, passive される, causative させる and causative-passive させられる; and of course る->た for past tense. I have no idea what you mean by "short causative form". I assumed your difficulty was just not having any concept of "causative-passive"; there should be a better duplicate for that but I couldn't find it.

Yes but it's not させられる here.  It's せられた

@KarlKnechtel is wrong here. There is no causative involved. 発せられた and 発された means the same thing. The former gives a more literacy feel. Related: Meaning of 課せられた.
